# Buildbot generator function buildtest.test

Tags: buildbot

After installing Buildbot I get the following error running the following command as per the [getting started docs](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/installation.html#running-buildbot-s-tests-optional):

In the terminal I type: `PYTHONPATH=. trial buildbot.test`

It outputs the following error (after many successful tests passed (2362)):

```
[ERROR]
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: exceptions.TypeError: <bound method TestLibVirtSlave.test_constructor_minimal of <buildbot.test.unit.test_buildslave_libvirt.TestLibVirtSlave testMethod=test_constructor_minimal>> is a generator function and therefore will never run

buildbot.test.unit.test_buildslave_libvirt.TestLibVirtSlave.test_constructor_minimal
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2371 tests in 9.604s

FAILED (skips=8, errors=1, successes=2362)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that test needs to be decorated with `@defer.inlineCallbacks`.  The newest version of Twisted (released after Buildbot-0.8.8) detects this as an error, whereas old versions just silently ignored it.  The fix is https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/commit/de8da868755810e453cbbb6c44793c53bb2f398b